# ASP.NET ComboBox is empty after submit button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I load Combobox from my database. First when page is loaded I get my list filled with data. 
when I click submit button my list becomes empty.
What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
public void ListCategory()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct category FROM kategorija", conn);
            conn.Open();


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct category FROM kategorija", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);

            ASPxComboBox1.Columns[0].Caption = "Категорија";
            ASPxComboBox1.Columns[0].FieldName = "Category";

            ASPxComboBox1.DataSource = ds;
            ASPxComboBox1.DataBind();         
        }
    }
```

and also on page load I do this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
           ListCategory();
       }  
   }
```

Comment: You have to move ListCategory() outside the if(!IsPostBack) condition. That's because you're doing a postback, so obviously the data isn't entered again.

Comment: I assume you have viewstate disabled for the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press a button, you are doing a `PostBack`. The condition `(!IsPostBack)` means "If this is not after a postback, do this". However, you *are* trying to do a PostBack, so the condition is just silly (Because when you do a postback, everything not in session is lost).

You need to move it out of the condition :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
           //Other stuff done only once during the page initialization
       }  

       ListCategory();
}
```

Or use the Session to remember your combobox values.

Comment: How to use this session? Can you give me an example? this works good. but I lose the selected value. 
I need to get selected value to use it on my query.
Thank you

Comment: @Barlet You can read that [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     ListCategory();
   }// witout Ispostback
```

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET webforms ViewState the data loaded into a form will persist after postbacks.  So normally the code you have where you check for a postback condition is efficient and works just fine.  However,  other factors such as disabling viewstate or manipulating the control in other areas of code can impact results after a postback.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled;//now a postback will lose data

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

In such a case you can remove the `IsPostBack` check or re-enable viewstate.  If the issue is with another area of code that you have not shown then it's best to fix that code instead of relying on an inefficient design by removing the check for `IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 0):

bind the data source outside the `!postback` check.